# spl_autoload_register is slow for WordPress sites

Tags: php, wp-admin

I have an existential doubt, I know that the tendency now of PHP 5 and PHP 7 is to load the classes dynamically with the function `spl_autoload_register` + `namespace` PHP projects such as invoice system, doctors, inventories, etc ...
It ends a luxury project. I have done many like this and they are perfect with `spl_autoload_register` + `namespace`.

BUT! THE PROBLEM WITH WORDPRESS

I'm doing a commercial WordPress plugin, and apply `spl_autoload_register` + `namespace` and this is my rule within the function `spl_autoload_register` so that they only load the classes with the prefix `PF`. So far this works perfect. I have no problems in my plugin development.

```
<?php
/**
 * Automatic upload framework files
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php
 * @package PF
 * @subpackage PF/Functions
 * @since 1.0 2019-02-18 23:55:42 Release
 */
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){

    // ─── If the specified $class_name does not include our namespace, duck out. ────────
    if ( false === strpos( $class_name, 'PF' ) ) return;

    // ─── Folders where the files can be ────────
    $folders = ['classes','interfaces'];

    // Split the class name into an array to read the namespace and class.
    $file_parts = explode( '\\', $class_name );

    // Do a reverse loop through $file_parts to build the path to the file.
    $namespace  = '';
    $file_name  = 'classes/class-init.php'; // Defaults file name
    for ( $i = count( $file_parts ) - 1; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
        // Read the current component of the file part.
        $current = strtolower( $file_parts[ $i ] );
        $current = str_ireplace( '_', '-', $current );
        // If we're at the first entry, then we're at the filename.
        if ( count( $file_parts ) - 1 === $i ) {
            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | If 'interface' is contained in the parts of the file name
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | Then define the $file_name differently so that it's properly loaded.
            | Otherwise, just set the $file_name equal to that of the class
            | filename structure.
            |
            */
            $name_part = strtolower( $file_parts[ count( $file_parts ) - 1 ] );
            if ( strpos( $name_part , 'class' ) ) {
                // For classes
                // NOTE here you can improve by putting the replacement as an array to avoid creating 2
                /*$file_name = 'class-' . str_replace( 'class', '', strtolower(
                                        str_replace( 'pf_', '', strtolower($name_part))) ) . '.php' ;*/
                $file_name = 'class-' . str_replace( array('class','pf_','pf_field_'), '', strtolower($name_part) ) . '.php';
            } else if( strpos( $name_part , 'interface' ) ) {
                // Grab the name of the interface from its qualified name.
                $interface_name = explode( '_', $file_parts[ count( $file_parts ) - 1 ] );
                $interface_name = $interface_name[0];

                $file_name = "interface-$interface_name.php";
            }
        } else {
            $namespace = '/' . $current . $namespace;
        }
    }

    // Now build a path to the file using mapping to the file location.
    $filepath  = trailingslashit( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . $namespace );
    $filepath .= $file_name;

    // If the file exists in the specified path, then include it. );
    //var_dump( file_exists( $filepath ) );
    if ( file_exists( $filepath ) ) {
        include_once $filepath;
    } else {
        wp_die(
            esc_html( "The file attempting to be loaded at $filepath does not exist." )
        );
    }
});
```

Where the line validate that only the classes that prefix PF enters the rest of validations, but here I have the big doubt.

```
if ( false === strpos( $class_name, 'PF' ) ) return;
```

**THE PROBLEM: WordPress is not a personal project or a personal system.**

Within my Wordpress there are about 20 plugins and 5 Themes installed.
Then the problem seems to be that this runs through all the files of all the installed plugins + all the installed themes files + all the files of the Wordpress Core, until finding the Class to execute it.

I think that the performance of my Plugin will be slow using `spl_autoload_register` since it is running through all the files in the wordpress(plugins+themes+core)

- Am I correct in my analysis?
- Is there a way to make it better?
- And does the other plugin or themes use other additional `spl_autoload_register`?

or for Wordpress it is simply better to use the `require_once` to specify which load and which does not load at the indicated time.

*Example:* https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/support/topic/loading-times-affected-since-current-version/

Comment: So you haven’t actually experienced any performance issues yet? You’re just wondering if you will?

Comment: I watch the page slower, besides that there was another plugin that had the prefix PF and I generate confusion in my classes, but I already solve it, I only have the performance problem.